# VS2015: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IFabricTestManagementClient4'

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

I am using VS2015 for this particular project but also using VS2017 for other projects.

Installed: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK                                                                         - 4.0.466.9590

VS Project Target framework: .NET Framework 4.6.2

VS reference System.Fabric: Runtime Version v4.0.30319 - Version 6.0.0.0

When I try to debug the application in VS2015, it turns out that it's throwing an exception when:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'IFabricTestManagementClient4'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{B96AA7D4-ACC0-4814-89DC-561B0CBB6028}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Can you help how to debug/resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a mismatch between the service code + nuget packages and the software version of the cluster.

The easiest way to fix, is to update everything to the latest version.